# Parsing value to INT cause overflow (nil) on 32 bits processor

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have a variable for exemple:

```
let variable:Int = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970*1000)
```

After some unexpected crashes I realized that processors with 32-bits (iphone 5,5c and iPad 2) cause error parsing the value.

I have read somewhere that this error happens because the 32-bits can only process 2^32 instead of the 64-bits which can process 2^64.

The point is if the value is higher than 2^32 in 32-bits and I make the transformation like this

```
Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970*1000)
```

Will work?

I don't know exactly how to explain it, hope it's enough clear, any further information just let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not that *"the 32-bits can only process 2^32"* but that `Int` is defined as a 32-bit integer on 32-bit processors. Your solution is safe.

Comment: Nice!!! Thanks Martin